# Protection against deletion of S3 server access logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, logging, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch

The server access logs of a bucket, say A, is required for auditing purposes. These logs are stored in a other bucket, say B. How can we make sure that no tampering or deletion of logs has happened from bucket B. It would have been easier to send these logs to Cloudwatch for better retention but I'm not sure if it is possible for S3 server access logs.

Comment: Add a bucket policy that include a `Deny` for `DeleteObject` and `DeleteObjects`!? And add versioning.

Comment: You can use CloudTrail to write S3 accesses to CloudWatch Logs. There are some differences between what you get with CloudTrail and what you get with bucket access logs; I can't remember what they are. But be aware that you would then have the problem of preventing someone from changing the retention period on your CloudWatch log groups.

Answer (score 0):

[Versioning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/Versioning.html), [MFA delete](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/MultiFactorAuthenticationDelete.html), and [Object lock](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-lock-console.html) are all features of S3 that will help you achieve your task.

Comment: Object lock, I'm afraid, cannot be turned on the bucket that is receiving the access logs.

Comment: Most people just use Versioning and MFA Delete to accomplish what you asked for. I added Object Lock in my answer to make you aware of that capability. You would have to create a new bucket to enable Object Lock I believe.